$\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{A}^2)$ as a free product with an amalgamated subgroup.
I am reading the second chapter of Shafarevich's book: Basic Algebraic Geometry.
At the end of this chapter he mentioned a fact about the structure of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{A}^2)$: Let $G$ denotes the subgroup of affine linear maps, $H$ denotes the subgroup of the maps of the form
$$ (x,y)\mapsto (\alpha x, \beta y+f(x))$$
Then
$$ \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{A}^2)\cong G*_{G\cap H}H $$
It seems that he omitted the proof, and the reference he gave just discussed some definition-issues.
How to prove this? Are there any references about the proof? Thanks in advance!
Edit: In exercises, he gave a hint for proving the uniqueness of the expression. It remains to show the existence of the expression, i.e. any automorphism can be written as a finite number of compositions of automorphisms in $G$ and $H$.
Thanks to Mohan, I found that this is a deep result first proved by Jung.

If I remember right, look at old papers of David Wright.

@Mohan Thank you! I have found a paper of him mentioning this result (Jung's theorem)
Reference: The Amalgamated Product Structure of the Tame Automorphism Group in Dimension Three, Transformation Groups, 20 (2015), 291-304 http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8325
